# Formula to derive probabilities when using 'gbm' method through 'caret' package in R

Tags: r, probability, roc, caret, boosting

I am training a classification problem by 'gbm' algorithm through 'caret' package in r.The response variable is a yes/nope type. Here 'objmodel' is the model I trained through method='gbm' and package 'caret'. Everything went smoothly but the problem is I would like to know the exact way the probabilities are computed so that I can take that formula/logic and apply that logic in a spreadsheet for example where there are the same predictor variables instead of relying on the R environment.

```
# probabilites 
library(pROC)
predictions <- predict(object=objModel, testDF[,predictorsNames], type='prob')
head(predictions)
##      nope    yes
## 1 0.07292 0.9271
## 2 0.76058 0.2394
## 3 0.43309 0.5669
## 4 0.67279 0.3272
## 5 0.67279 0.3272
## 6 0.54616 0.4538
```

Kindly let me know if that is possible. I used http://amunategui.github.io/binary-outcome-modeling/ as my guide.